# Overfitting on a small dataset while finetuning Layoutlm. Which regularization techniques are suggested?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

I am currently using huggingface package to train my layoutlm model. However, I am experiencing overfitting for a token classification task. My dataset contains only 400 documents. I know it is very small dataset but I don't have any other chance to collect more data.

My results are in the table below. I have tried `weight_decay=0.1` which is a high number in my opinion and also tried early stopping based on f1 score and loss seperately, but they didn't work.
[image]

Which regularisation techniques should I try extra? Do you have any solution to overfitting to a small dataset with bert-like models?

Comment: That is a small number in weight decay terms. Other easy regularization techniques include dropout.

Comment: I don't think it is a small value. Pls look at https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-reduce-overfitting-in-deep-learning-with-weight-regularization/